# Applying a BiFunction from a map

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to apply a BiFunction to method parameters in a generic way so that I can get the function from a map:

```java
    public class ElementFactoryTest {
      private final static Map<String,
          BiFunction<
              ? extends Element,
              String,
              ? extends MetaElement<? extends MetaElement<?, ?>, ? extends Element>>>
          functionMap = new HashMap<>();
    
      public static <
          E extends Element,
          M extends MetaElement<? extends MetaElement<?, ?>, ? extends Element>>
      void registerFactoryFunction(String type, BiFunction<E, String, M> factoryFunction) {
          functionMap.put(type, factoryFunction);
      }
    
      public static <E extends Element>
      MetaElement<?, ?> getElementList(String type, E element, String namespacePrefix) {
        return functionMap.get(type).apply(element, namespacePrefix);
      }
    }
```

The `registerFactoryFunction` method code compiles fine, but I don't understand why the line

```java
return functionMap.get(type).apply(element, namespacePrefix);
```

does not compile. Is it not possible to do this?

Update 1

Changing `extends` to `super` as @josejuan suggests allows the code to compile but the client code that registers the bifunctions fails to compile with the error "reason: Incompatible types: Element is not convertible to ElementSubclass":

```java
ElementFactoryTest.registerElementFactory("elementType", MetaElementSubclass::build);

public static MetaElement<MetaElementSubclass, ElementSubclass> build(ElementSubclass element, String namespace) {
....
  }
```

update 2

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```java
public class ElementFactoryTest {
  static class Parent {
    public String getString() {
      return "parent";
    }
  }

  static class Child extends Parent {
    public String getString() {
      return "child";
    }
  }

  private final static Map<String,
      BiFunction<? super Parent, String, String>>
      functionMap = new HashMap<>();

  public static void registerFactoryMethod(String type,
                                           BiFunction<? super Parent, String, String> factoryFunction) {
    functionMap.put(type, factoryFunction);
  }

  public static <E extends Parent>
  String getString(String type, E element, String namespacePrefix) {
    return functionMap.get(type).apply(element, namespacePrefix);
  }

  public static String build(Child child, String namespacePrefix) {
    return namespacePrefix + child.getString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElementFactoryTest.registerFactoryMethod("child", ElementFactoryTest::build);
    String childString = ElementFactoryTest.getString("child", new Child(), "prefix.");
  }
}
```

The line:

```
ElementFactoryTest.registerFactoryMethod("child", ElementFactoryTest::build);
```

fails to compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @josejuan, I added a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fail because your bifunctions **must** admit **any** `? super Parent` but you are providing an implementation valid **only** for `Child super Parent`.

The compiler is trying to tell you that you should generalize your `Test::build` function.

[image]

Without knowing the details of what you need to do, your least bad approach is to downcast at runtime, but surely your original problem admits a compile-time solution (please do not edit your question, create another one if you consider it necessary).

```
public static String build(Parent child, String namespacePrefix) {
    if(child instanceof Child)
        return namespacePrefix + child.getString();
    throw new RuntimeException("Arghh!");
}
```

testing with

```
System.out.println(Test.getString("child", new Child(), "prefix."));
System.out.println(Test.getString("child", new Parent(), "prefix."));
```

with output

```
prefix.child
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Arghh!
```

Further reading:

[Covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

[Covariance and Contravariance in Java](https://medium.com/@yuhuan/covariance-and-contravariance-in-java-6d9bfb7f6b8e)

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get my first attempt to work with a cast.

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast the BiFunction before calling apply like:

```java
  public static <E extends Parent>
  String getString(String type, E element, String namespacePrefix) {
    return ((BiFunction<E, String, String>) functionMap.get(type)).apply(element, namespacePrefix);
  }
```

`E` is defined as `E extends Parent` and the parameter in the `BiFunction` definition is `? extends Parent` so it seems reasonable enough.

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it's the only one that worked for me.

The minimal reproducible example is:

```java
public class ElementFactoryTest {

  static class Parent {
    public String getString() {
      return "parent";
    }
  }

  static class Child extends Parent {
    public String getString() {
      return "child";
    }

    public static String build(Child child, String namespacePrefix) {
      return namespacePrefix + child.getString();
    }
  }

  static class GrandChild extends Child {
    public String getString() {
      return "grand child";
    }

    public static String build(Child child, String namespacePrefix) {
      return namespacePrefix + child.getString();
    }
  }

  private final static Map<String,
      BiFunction<? extends Parent, String, String>>
      functionMap = new HashMap<>();

  public static <E extends Parent>
  void registerElementFactory(String type,
                              BiFunction<E, String, String> factoryFunction) {
    functionMap.put(type, factoryFunction);
  }

  public static <E extends Parent>
  String getString(String type, E element, String namespacePrefix) {
    return ((BiFunction<E, String, String>) functionMap.get(type)).apply(element, namespacePrefix);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ElementFactoryTest.registerElementFactory("child", Child::build);
    ElementFactoryTest.registerElementFactory("grand-child", GrandChild::build);
    String childString = ElementFactoryTest.getString("child", new Child(), "prefix.");
    System.out.println(childString);

    String grandChild = ElementFactoryTest.getString("grand-child", new GrandChild(), "prefix.");
    System.out.println(grandChild);
  }
}
```